# Why #pragma is not working on ideone?

Tags: c

Consider the below program:

```
#pragma startup foo1
#pragma exit foo2

void foo1()
{
    printf("Called before main\n");
}

void foo2()
{
    printf("Called after main\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("main called\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as: http://ideone.com/ooMFI

```
main called
```

**Why the `pragma` is not working here?**
**Why foo1() & foo2() are not called?**

Comment: What C compiler as Pragmas differ between compilers? and weer did you see this working?

Comment: On what compiler have you seen those pragmas work? ideone uses gcc and pragmas are compiler specific, so if it was another compiler on which you've previously used them, there's a good chance gcc doesn't support those pragmas

Comment: pragmas are working on turbo c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because none of these pragmas are recognized by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html). In general, stay clear of pragmas if you're trying to write portable code, because they differ per compiler and even per platform within the same compiler family.